# How do I copy a UNIX Executable File with NSFileManager?

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

I am trying to use `NSFileManager` `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:` to move a UNIX executable file (a command line program) from one directory to another but I always get an error that says the URL type is unsupported.  I assume this is because without an extension on the file it is being viewed as a directory but I'm not sure.  Is it possible to move this type of file with `NSFileManager`?

Edit:
Here is my code

```
#define SAVE_DIR   [@"~/Library/Prog" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
#define PROG_PATH  [SAVE_DIR stringByAppendingString:@"/ProgCom"]
#define RESOURCES  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
#define LOCAL_PROG [RESOURCES stringByAppendingString:@"/ProgCom"]

-(void)moveProg
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *fromURL = [NSURL URLWithString:LOCAL_PROG];
    NSURL *toURL = [NSURL URLWithString:PROG_PATH];

    NSLog(@"%@", [fromURL path]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [toURL path]);

    if ([fMan fileExistsAtPath:[fromURL path]]) {
        [fMan copyItemAtURL:fromURL
                      toURL:toURL
                      error:&error];
        if (error)
            [NSApp presentError:error];
    }
}
```

The error I receive:

`The file couldn't be opened because the specified URL type isn't supported.`

And finally what gets logged:

```
fromURL = /Users/Nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prog-dpnblqaraeuecyadjgizbinfrtcm/Build/Products/Debug/Prog.app/Contents/Resources/ProgCom

toURL = /Users/Nick/Library/Prog/ProgCom
```

Comment: It should work. There's no special trick and it doesn't care about the file extension. It sounds like your URL is incorrect. Log both URLs and post them in your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is you're using `+[NSURL URLWithString:]`. This is producing an invalid URL, since you're not actually giving it one. What you want is `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`, which will produce a `file:///Users/Nick/...` URL.

Comment: Wow...I feel really dumb for forgetting about `fileURLWithPath`.  Thank you for the help.